# How can I say Coaching in plural?

Tags: parenthetical-plural

So I've been googling for a while and I see that there are sources who says 
 "Coaching" in plural is "Coachings" and other sources says that "Coachings" is a typo error.

These are the sources who says it's a correct word:

- https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coachings
- https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/coaching.html

The sources who says that it's an incorrect word are:

- Office Word 2016 Spellchecker
- JetBrains WebStorm IDE Spellchecker
- Chrome built-in Spellchecker.
- Couldn't find the word "Coachings" in MacOS dictionary.

In case it's an incorrect word, Are there any alternatives?

What I'm trying to say is something like "A Coach can coach multiple of Coaching(s)".

I know that "Coaching" is a verb of the word "Coach", but lately, people start to use it as term also. I'm want to know how can I express the term in plural.

Comment: A coach can coach more than one person or group at a time. "coach multiple of coaching(s) does not really convey any meaning.

Comment: By ‘coaching’, do you mean ‘student’ or ‘session’?

Comment: @Lawrence A session

Comment: Then why not call it a 'session'?

Comment: Can you give more than one example (with links) that says when 'coachings' is correct and when it is an error? I'd like to see examples supporting what you say.

Comment: @Mitch
1. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coachings
2. https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/coaching.html

I wouldn't trust the 2nd source, but the 1st source in my opinion looks legit.

I get an error whenever I type it by a spellchecker.

Comment: @EliyaCohen 1) I trust both about the same (that is, not much).  2) You should add those links and, separately, the kind of spellchecker you're using into your question above. The sources you can trust are Merriam-Webster and OED (and some other on-line dictionaries) also a google search might find you many instances of it that seem like not typos. To my ear,it is an infelicitous but legal new word formation. It feels very ungainly to me. There are probably much better sounding alternatives (given in answers).

Comment: Yet, felicitious and gainly to me. Very common in the states. One used to be disciplined  ... now the pc is coached.  I myself had had many **coachings** as i progressed in my profession!  And none were  err ... pleasant.

Comment: Please ***include*** the research you have found. Don't just allude to it. That is, include specific uses of **coachings**. As far as mass and count nouns in English, almost all nouns can be used as either: for example, *researches* (plural count) is valid as well as *research* (mass).

Comment: Thanks @EliyaCohen. Please [edit] your question to include the information you've added in comments. On this site, comments are considered to be only temporary notes. They can be removed at any time, without notice. It's better to include important information in the question proper.

Comment: Thank your for the clarification. I have updated my answer with the sources.

Answer (score 1):

The word “courses” should work instead of “coachings”? Coachings seems incorrect.

A coach can provide multiple trainings.
Or
A coach can train multiple teams or players.

Comment: It's more like a type of training. In a nutshell the Coach is a gamer who can coach another players. The coach can coach on many other games. I'm not sure if the word "course" should work in this case. I'm still having a hard time to find a word that can explain that.

Comment: A coach can train multiple players.

Comment: Not sure who gave me negative points and why?

Comment: Sorry, not me. So I can't exactly know why.

Comment: multiple trainings with an s is as bad as coaching with an s....

Comment: Coaching with an s ... not bad at all. Me thinks this is another difference between the 2 sides of the 'pond'.

Comment: Why did you get negative points? I didn't give them to you, but I can guess: "coaching" can only be replaced by "courses" sometimes; usually, they mean different things.

Answer (score 1):

The object phrase "multiple of coaching(s)" is not proper and is awkward. A different phrase would convey the intended meaning correctly such as "in multiple areas", "in multiple disciplines" or just "multiple subjects" as three examples.

However, if you want to convey multiple groups, people, or teams, then use these similarly as object(s) to be coached. If you wish to express "multiple coaching sessions", then that phrase could be used for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

A [Google Books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22coachings%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1994,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) shows many instances of "coachings" that imply the use of "coaching" to denote an individual coaching tip or session. While *I* hadn't encountered this before, it seems established.

Answer (score 0):

coaching (plural **coachings**) [wictionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coaching)

> The act by which someone is coached.

As in:

> 2009, Decisions and Orders of the U.S. National Labor Relations Board:
>
> While Promedica may indeed have been an unfair labor practice case, the salient issue involved whether **coachings** were
>   disciplinary [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coaching)

Not an uncommon usage in the U.S. Here are a couple of links showing other diverse examples:  [coachings and training](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLz6bhvrzaAhVrm-AKHf0cANUQFggxMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.conaquila.de%2Finternational-teams%2F&usg=AOvVaw1vftr-s-TdlMbFISfCY1zD) & [Life Coachings | LinkedIn](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLz6bhvrzaAhVrm-AKHf0cANUQFghIMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fuk.linkedin.com%2Fcompany%2Flife-coachings&usg=AOvVaw1j8NO-IaM37S7-XAh6I2v0)

Answer (score 0):

"Coaching" is an uncountable 'singularia tantum' (always singular) noun, so it cannot be used in plural.
https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/coaching